# My query does not return any users that are in admin role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity

The context is i'm using Microsoft Identity 2 framework.

I have the following query:

```
// Succesfully gets the admin role
IdentityRole role = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == RoleChoices.ADMIN).First(); 

return this.context
           .Users.Include( x => x.Roles)
           .Where(x => x.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));
```

Where am I going wrong?

I want to return only admin users

Comment: Can you try this: `var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "admin");`

Comment: Is the problem with your first or second query? Also, what does `RoleChoices.ADMIN` map to?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, it's actually the second part not returning anything, when atleast 1 should be returned.

Comment: What are the `page` and `amount` values? Also, what is `PrepareAllUsersQuery` doing?

Comment: Are you thinking that the query should be working?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess and say that it's the second half of your predicate in the Where statement: `r.UserId == x.Id`  What happens if you remove that piece?  Also, have you sanity checked your `Page` and `Amount` variables?

Comment: Both looking good! And removing the r.UserId == x.Id unfortunately does not work either.

Comment: you have users in your `Users` database that have the `RoleId` of an admin ... right? Can you please inspect the code (to get the `role.Id`) and check if you really have users with that? Also: have you told EF (it is EF isn't it?) to include the `Roles` into the query? If not `x.Roles` might be empty ;)

Comment: There's a joining table: IdentityUserRoles, this relates to Users table and IdentityRoles table

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Skip` and the `Take` and see if that returns anything?

Comment: Also if you are querying the users roles collection, surely you wouldn't need to check the UserId of the role.